# Delay in response from Tensorflow model deployed into Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, tensorflow-serving

How to improve response time for a model deployed in Kubernetes?

I get a response time of 0.18 sec from localhost Tensorlfow model, whereas the same model hosted on Kubenetes cluster gives me response time of 4 sec.

Kubernetes Cluster- I created a simple deployment and service to host model. There is only one active node for this deployment.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is normal behaviour that delay in response on Kubernets cluster is higher. Main goal of Kubernetes is to manage resources.

Prediction speed has a direct relationship to the cost of serving, since it is directly related to the amount of compute resources necessary to make a prediction. The time it takes to make a prediction will always be a critical variable in any formula that measures prediction throughput. Faster predictions means more prediction throughput on the same hardware, translating into reduced cost.

More information you can find here: [tensorflow-performance](https://hackernoon.com/how-we-improved-tensorflow-serving-performance-by-over-70-f21b5dad2d98).

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same thing and was finally able to replicate the kubernetes behavior locally by adding some resource limits to my docker-compose under "deploy" like the following

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: 1
          memory: 2048M
```

From there I could replicate the behavior locally and test what resources Kubernetes would need to behave how I wanted it. I found that upping the `cpu` on the Kubernetes cluster was the primary driver of performance.

I'm not 100% convinced that it's the only reason that model response time is slower in k8s, but it is a factor. I'll update this if I discover anything else.